# Creating folder shortcuts in the Windows 7 taskbar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, shortcuts

Say I have multiple locations that I'm working with fairly regularly, and want access to them quickly - 1-2 clicks or key strokes. Is it possible to do something like pin an explorer shortcut to the taskbar?

How do I set this up in Windows 7?

I figure Autohotkey + some scripting would do it but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel if I'm missing something about Windows 7 file management.

Comment: And standard Shortcuts to folders won't suffice (say, on your desktop, or pinned to your taskbar)?

Comment: is it possible to pin an explorer shortcut to the taskbar? That would work.

Comment: Just figured it out - that was exactly what I was missing.

Comment: Another tip for speedy access: by default, you can launch pinned items with Windows Key + numbers 1 through 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pin Explorer to the Taskbar (drag an Explorer Icon to the Taskbar and it will pin).

If you drag multiple folder shortcuts to the task bar (one at a time) it will show as (only) one Explorer icon, but if you hover over it, it will pop up a menu with those shortcuts available to click on (called the Jump List).

[image: Jump List]

[Check out here for more Taskbar info](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/help/better-stronger-faster-the-windows-7-taskbar).